# Removing extra parentheses in Scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

Using a Scheme-like language, I am converting

```
(quote (lambda (a b) (* a b) (+ a b))))
```

to:

```
(quote (lambda (a) (lambda (b) (+ a b) (* a b))))
```

but with my current implementation I am getting an extra pair of parenthesis around the expressions `(+ a b)` and `(* a b)`:

```
(lambda (a) (lambda (b) ((+ a b) (* a b))))
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to fix this problem, but can't figure it out. I feel like the fix should be trivial.

Here is my code currently:

```
(define (conv lyst)

  (define (helper args)
    (cond
      ((null? args) (append (cddr lyst) args))
      (else (cons (car lyst) 
                  (cons (list (car args)) 
                        (list (helper (cdr args))))))))

  (cond
    ((eq? 1 (length (car (cdr lyst)))) lyst)
    (else (helper (car (cdr lyst))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your implementation can be simplified. This should work:

```
(define (conv lyst)  
  (define (helper args)
    (if (null? (cdr args))
        (cons 'lambda
              (append (list (list (car args)))
                      (cddr lyst)))
        (list  'lambda
               (list (car args))
               (helper (cdr args)))))
  (helper (cadr lyst)))
```

Or even simpler, using [quasiquoting and splicing](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html):

```
(define (conv lyst)  
  (define (helper args)
    (if (null? (cdr args))
        `(lambda (,(car args)) ,@(cddr lyst))
        `(lambda (,(car args)) ,(helper (cdr args)))))
  (helper (cadr lyst)))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(conv '(lambda (a b) (* a b) (+ a b)))
=> '(lambda (a) (lambda (b) (* a b) (+ a b)))
```

Comment: Nice! That is a lot simpler. The only thing I had to fix with your first solution is add an extra append after '(lambda).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that in MIT Scheme `append` only accepts two parameters; I updated my answer.